# Android: ListView problem

Tags: android, listview, scroll

Hi I have a problem with ListView scrolling. My activity layout:

```
<ScrollView>
  <ReleativeLayout>
      <ListView>
      <... other controls>
```

When this list view has a lot of elements, so that they do not fit on the screen, I cannot scroll. The interesting part is that the scroll works in landscape orientation, but not in portrait.

Does any one has a suggestion on how to tweak my layout in order to allow scrolling?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do NOT place a listview inside a scrollview, google says it doesnt work, and every time I've tried it brings problems.

Think of this, when you swipe your finger over a the listview, what should scroll, the listview or the scrollview?

You are going to have to rethink that portion of the UI.

Comment: It's not just that it doesn't work, it's that it makes no sense. :) ListView pages in a small portion of content within a window; it exists to optimize the presentation of unbounded dynamic content. If you let a ListView fill the effectively infinite height of a ScrollView you add a ton of complexity for no benefit. You might as well call layout.addView(adapter.getView(position, null, layout)) in a loop with a LinearLayout and add that to your ScrollView. Then when you end up with a lot of data it will get slow and use a lot of memory. Then you will see why ListView does things this way. :)

Comment: Thanks for the aditional input adamp.

Comment: Ok, but how can I manage a listview with a lot of items which do not fit the screen? Is there any tips? If I understand you correctly, my only option is to create an activity with listview only?

Comment: Anyway, I managed to resolve my issue with help of ListView.addFooterView method. It looks okay. Thanks for your answer!